# Does Reporting Services has code behind and object events?

Tags: events, reporting-services, reporting, code-behind

Does Microsoft Reporting Services (Report Builder) has code behind and object events like Fast Reports, Rave Reports and others?

Sample:

In FastReports and Rave, we have objects like MemoView and DataMemo. They contains some events like OnAfterPrint, OnBeforePrint... We also have page events, like PageOnBeforePrint and others...

I want write code in Reporting Services (Report Builder) because I have rich visualizations and I want insert events in objects. Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the bad news, but no.

SSRS doesn't have a much of an event model. You can certainly customize the OnClick events for many items, but beyond that will be tricky. You can also add custom code, but that is basically called during the data build and render, and then not much after that.

(SSRS tries to treat HTML, PDF, Excel and other formats equally. I think it would be hard to handle events from all of these formats.)